# Why does resetting my password to log into Careers break my Stack Exchange login?

Tags: support, jobs, login

I have no idea how to login to your web site http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

I somehow managed to have 4 different accounts there, none of which work for me. It seems everytime I login I need to reset my password, which will then work for the careers site, but then locks me out of the other sites.

There's no way to simply reset, it keeps trying to use my old account.

I am "chovy" on SO. How do I login with this one and only one account?

I think this is some relic from the old openid login, as I never really created a stack exchange account properly before you guys stopped supporting it a couple of years ago.

Its very frustrating. My account 'chovy' on stackexchange is not associated with my account on careers.

Comment: -1 for the non-descriptive (to put it mildly) title.

Comment: @sha careers.exhcnage.com <<-- typo

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I know, didn't bother to fix due to crappy title. (OP doesn't deserve it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard then why did you bother to add a tag?

Comment: @Jan for the Careers team to be able to see it, just in case. :)

Comment: Aside from the terrible title, this question is completely useless. Going to a support forum and just saying "this all sucks, make me happy" is not going to achieve something. You have made zero effort to provide details of the problems you're having or errors you're receiving, or what you expect us to do to resolve it for you.

Comment: **careers.exhcnage.com** - fix the typo

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion even fixing the typo won't help. `careers.exchange.com` doesn't exist.

Comment: i added better description

Comment: Cheers for the good edit, downvote undone and voted to reopen, however you miss the point that Careers account is never really associated with any other Stack Exchange account, it's not listed in the network profile of any user.

Comment: Well I should still be able to login with same SE credentials.y point is that doesn't work correctly. At least in older accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Careers has its own login system, separate from the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

You will need to create an account if you don't already have one. If you do, please send us an email at careers@stackoverflow.com with your name and e-mail address and I can get everything straightened out.

P.S.
We agree the current login system is kludgy. It's on our very large TODO list of things to fix up.

Comment: I think I triggered some sort of demonic bug. If I change my password for careers, I can no longer login to SO, and if I change my password for SO I can no longer login to careers.

Comment: @chovy just curious, is this still an issue?

Comment: yes, i have to reset my password everytime I login here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/es4oscg9zwkh9if/Screenshot%202015-01-27%2000.26.44.png?dl=0